# Question on the Grammar in Genesis 27:15 and Exodus 12:16

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I am curious regarding the phrase "bigdei Esav, b’nah hagadol, hachamudos" (Genesis (Toldot) Chapter 27, Verse 15). Beged is masculine, referring to clothing, and chamudos, seemingly related to clothing, is feminine. If you have an explanation or if chamudos hints at an esoteric idea, I'd love to know.

I also have a similar question about the grammar in "kol melacha lo yay-aseh bohem" (Exodus (Parshas Bo) Chapter 12, Verse 16). Melacha is feminine, and yay-aseh (not ya-aseh), meaning "it will not be done," is masculine. Any insights?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Genesis.27.15

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Genesis.27.15.1

Comment: "ya'aseh" would mean "he/it will/shall not do." Do you mean "te'aseh"?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Torah%2C_Exodus.12.16.1

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Exodus.12.16.2

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a problem. In Hebrew, the suffix for "multiple" combined with "belonging to" is the same for male and female.